# TFS 2012 rolling build builds earlier than defined

Tags: tfs

If have set TFS 2012 to Rolling builds and defined 15 minutes as the minimum time between builds.

Now I see the following:
Build started 10:34:48, completed 10:39:49
Build started 10:46:53, completed 10:47:01 (fast, because it failed)

The time between those build is only 12 minutes, not 15, why?

Comment: Are you on the latest update (Update 3) for TFS 2012?

Comment: Are you sure that no one manually started the build?

Comment: We're using Update 2 only. We have not triggered a build manually in this example.

Comment: We updated to TFS2012 Update 3 now. Still not better: build started 12:48:12 and 12:56:33.

Comment: Sorry, Update 3 really helps. The times mentioned in the last comment were the completed times, not started times.
@MikeDouglasDev: please make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the latest update (Update 3) to your TFS 2012 installation.  Update 4 was also just released.  I haven't seen if there are any fixes related.

I'm glad that it helped.

Thanks,
Mike